# What does represent the random variable $X^i$ associated to a Bernoulli law?

Tags: probability

Let's consider a random variable $X^i$ that follows a Bernoulli law of parameter $p$, where $p$ represents a probability of a given phenomena. The experiment is made $N$ times : $i\in [1 ; N]$.
What does represent $X^i$ :

1. is it representing whether a given experiment has given or not the phenomena ?
2. is it representing the *proportion* of the phenomena ?
3. is it representing the *number of observations* of the phenomena ?

(I think that it could not be (2), since the result for a Bernoulli is either 0 or 1).

Comment: Well, (1) and (3) is the same thing, if for (3) you assume (as you should) that there was *one* experiment done in total.

Comment: @Stinking Bishop : yes, but let's assume that we do N times the operation. I reformulate the question. Thanks

Comment: Then this may not be *Bernoulli* distribution but *binomial* distribution.

Comment: @Stinking Bishop : do you mean that $X^i$ is not following a bernoulli distribution ?

Comment: Each $X^i$ will follow Bernoulli distribution, and their *sum* will follow binomial distribution (provided that all $X^i$ are independent). $X^i$ can be $0$ or $1$ and it is the number of times the phenomenon was seen in the experiment $i$. (Not seen or seen once.) The sum $\sum_{i=1}^n X^i$ is the number of times the phenomenon was observed in all $N$ experiments.

Comment: @Stinking Bishop : thanks a lot. You saved me 3 days of searching for the *intepretation*.

Comment: Glad to help...